# Windows Explorer Links Returning

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-explorer

I've got a GPO setup which deletes the generic default links in each users profile and adds some items to the links. For some reason, the deleted links "Desktop" and "Downloads" keep returning after being deleted. Even if I manually delete them or set them as hidden, when I log out and back in they are back.

I've never had this issue before. Does anyone have any idea what the cause to this may be?

Answer (score 0):

It possible to provide an export of the GPO and maybe on RSOP of one impacted client machine to have more details.

At the same time, you can use the GPS Search (http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/) to explain us which settinsg you applied in your GPOs and for which client version ?

Thanks,

Douda,